# Are there contractions for past tense of lexical verbs? (was and were)

Tags: contractions

For **present tense** (declarative) of lexical verbs (to be) we have contractions for all pronouns:

- (I am = I’m. You are = you’re. He is = he’s. She  is = she’s. It is = it’s. We are = we’re. They are = they’re.).

The same is for the **future tense**:

- (I'll, you'll, he'll, she'll, it'll, we'll they'll).

My question is about the **past tense** (declaratives) of lexical verbs (**was and were**). Do we have *contractions* for them? If we do, what are they? and If not, why? Using google I didn't find a clear answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

None that I can think of in common usage besides negative contractions (wasn't, weren't etc.) although I think you were asking about pronoun-verb contractions.

Very rarely I've heard the lexical form of have in a sentence like "I'd a friend once" (I once had a friend), although that's a relatively obscure way of phrasing that sentence, and one which lends it a sort of whimisical British tone.

Comment: Clearly, there are none.

Answer (score -1):

Contractions of phrases like "she was" or "they were" aren't commonly used. It makes sense - they'd probably be undistinguishable from contractions of "she is" and "they are" and cause many a confusion...